# Excel 2016 changed text style when opening

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-formatting, styles

We are using Microsoft Excel 2016 on Windows 10. We are using tables with filled information. All text and numbers are normal black Style. After some changes in document (editing text or numbers) we are saving file and closing Excel.

When opening saved `.xlsx` file, Excel opens it in different text Style (not the one that was saved). It is grey Style. All text and numbers are Grey Style.

I know it can be custom created Excel add-in which runs macro every time Excel is opened and reformats Styling according to add-in. But there are no add-ins in this case.

What could be the other reasons?